# Add values in a sheet together and present the answer on another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 values in sheet 1. I want to add those 2 values together and have the answer on sheet 2 (code also in sheet 2).

```
    Sub mycode5()
    
    Worksheets("Part4").Range("L7").Formula = Worksheets("Part2a").Range("K3").Formula + Worksheets("Part2a").Range("K4").Formula
    
    End Sub
```

Tried this but it did not work.

Comment: Have you tried using `.Value` instead of `.Formula` ?

Answer (score 0):

Basic example of what you can do :

```
Private Sub main_function()
    Dim Value1 As Integer, Value2 as Integer, Result as Integer
    
    Value1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value 
    Value2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value
    Result = Value1 + Value2
    
    WorkSheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value = Result 
End Sub
```

There are more efficient ways to achieve it but .Value is good enough to obviously get the value from a cell.